# Common framework for publishing books online

Tags: publishing, web-publishing

[Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) are using some similarly-looking web publishing platforms (with rigid TOC/chapters/paragraphs+comments structure). However, I haven't found any reference to the platform used on the corresponding websites. Is there a publishing framework or CMS similar to the ones mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459569/is-django-book-platform-available) about the availability of Djangobook's code may help.