# Is Django Book platform available?

Tags: django, publishing, platform

The [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/) has a neat content publishing template. Anyone knows if it's available for public use?

Alternatively, what Django sources would you recommend as an easy to use, out of the box CMS?

Comment: Do you mean the source code backing http://djangobook.com?  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: @S.Lott My interpretation was definitely that konzepz wanted the source backing djangobook.com

Comment: @Hank Gay: While you're probably correct, the question -- as stated -- doesn't say that very clearly.  It makes the question hard to search for, and not very usable as written.

Comment: @konzepz: Please don't comment on your own question.  Please fix your question instead of commenting on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [post](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/d02ef257f611c358) on the mailing list, the source hasn't been released, and it doesn't look like it will be.

I'd be interested in seeing the code as well.

All we know is that it uses the YUI / extjs comment system. Based on that mailing list post it sounds like the code the Django site uses is from a BSD licensed version of the code, so perhaps you could use that javascript as a starting point.

Ian Bicking created a [similar commentary system](http://blog.ianbicking.org/doc-comments.html) implemented as WSGI middleware. Here are the [docs](http://pythonpaste.org/commentary/) for it. Looks like the source is [here](http://svn.w4py.org/Paste/apps/Commentary/).

Comment: Last paragraph is now useless, links are not working anymore.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea Not so, the links in the last paragraph do work.

Answer (score 10):

[The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/) is now available in sources (both examples and book content in **reStructuredText**):

```
  $ svn co http://djangobook.com/svn/trunk/en
```

I read book and try examples without leaving Emacs!!

**PS** Seems SVN server is down. Check https://github.com/jacobian/djangobook.com or even https://github.com/search?q=djangobook

**NOTE** book was originally published by Apress in 2009 and covered Django version 1.0. Since then it has languished and, in places, is **extremely out of date**

Answer (score 7):

There's a free, and fully supported, Django package that we built to have the same functionality as the Django Book site.

http://ucomment.org

That codebase is used on several publicly-available websites, such at http://connectmv.com/tutorials

We do our best to maintain this package, so please give it a try and send us your feedback.

Kevin

Comment: Sites are all dead, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Remark box is built on the same principles as the DjangoBook comment system, its a free service for small sites.

And unlike other projects, it can be used on any HTML page, integration is just a few JavaScript lines. You might want to check it out if you like the DjangoBook-like contextual comments.

Their front page has a live demo http://www.remarkbox.com/

Answer (score 1):

there is also commentpress, a similar comment model for wordpressm made by the institute for the future of the book http://www.futureofthebook.org/commentpress/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Open Book Platform (Chinese)](http://code.google.com/p/openbookplatform/)

Its author, limodou, made a clone of the Django Book platform very early on.

Comment: Can you see any download link over there? Can't see nothing.

Comment: It looks like only the source is available. See this page for instructions on how to do a checkout: http://code.google.com/p/openbookplatform/source/checkout

Comment: Unfortunately the limodou code is quite old. Browsing SVN indicates it mostly dates to February, 2007. It was written against an old version of Django and might require a fair amount of work to run with 1.1.1 stable. If I can't find something usable I'm going to have to write this myself. And, yes, it will be FLOSS.